# How to trigger $watch after 2s delay or execute the last condition of a subscribed property of a scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, delay

I have a search input which triggers watch and then send a new request to DB

```
var timeoutPromise;
var delayInMs = 2000;
$scope.$watch('search', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise); 
    timeoutPromise = $timeout(function(){ 
        $scope.nameFilter = '&filter[]=Name,cs,' + $scope.search;
        $scope.updatePage(1);
    });
}, delayInMs);
```

The main goal of the delay was triggering `watch` not on each new character in the search input but after amending at least several letters.

Unfortunately, this watch just put all requests in a queue and executes all request after the delay.

Please help me

Comment: You can use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) and [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) with the `debouce` property. So you're code would look something along the lines of `<input type="search" ng-model="search" ng-change="searchFunction()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }" />`

Comment: Where are you triggering the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular comes with things like this built in, just in a slightly different way.
I would suggest doing it like this, the part which delays the change is in the [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

**JS**

```
$scope.search = "";

$scope.searchFunction = function(){ 
    $scope.nameFilter = '&filter[]=Name,cs,' + $scope.search;
    $scope.updatePage(1);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="searchFunction()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }" />
```

You may also want to take advantage of the input type *search*

Answer (score 0):

## Update

If you want to wait for few milliseconds before firing ng-change you can use ng-model-options as Suggested by  George

```
<input type="search" ng-model="search" ng-change="searchFunction()" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }" />
```

---

If you insist on doing the way you've written you can use the below code

You do not need `$scope.$watch` since angular automatically updates the search property. So use `$timeout` to delay the execution

```
var timeoutPromise;
var delayInMs = 2000;
timeoutPromise = $timeout(function() {
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);
        $scope.nameFilter = '&filter[]=Name,cs,' + $scope.search;
        $scope.updatePage(1);
}, delayInMs);
```

Comment: All this does is delay the creation of the watch by wathever you delay you input, but the watch will still trigger with every character press after it has been registered.

Comment: The only useful part in your updated answer is the ngModelOptions. The second part with the timeout doesn't have a use anymore after you've added ngModelOptions.

Comment: We can use any of the two methods `ngModelOptions` or `$timeout`

Comment: I agree, the solution with the $timeout would work very well if ngModelOptions wasn't an option for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `delayInMs` is a third argument to `$watch` instead of being an argument to `$timeout`. The following should work normally:

```
var timeoutPromise;
var delayInMs = 2000;
$scope.$watch('search', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise); 
    timeoutPromise = $timeout(function(){ 
        $scope.nameFilter = '&filter[]=Name,cs,' + $scope.search;
        $scope.updatePage(1);
    }, delayInMs);
});
```